# slice(start, stop, None) vs slice(start, stop, 1)

Tags: python, slice

I was surprised to read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) that

> The `start` and `step` arguments default to `None`

since it also says:

> ```
> slice(start, stop, step=1)
> ```
>
> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by range(start, stop, step).

So I expected the default argument value for the `step` parameter to be `1`.

I know that `slice(a, b, None) == slice(a, b, 1)` returns `False`, but I am curious if `slice(a, b, None)` always returns the same slice as `slice(a, b, 1)`, or if there is some example that I haven't been able to think of for which they will return different slices.

I couldn't find anything about this in the extensive post on slicing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)

Comment: That is likely the difference between a defaulted argument and a default behaviour. `step` is processed as 1 when None but still stored as None (which is different tan 1)

Comment: Hmm, I think you have found a minor documentation bug.  The correct signature for slice is `slice(start, stop[, step])`.

Comment: Someone may implement a function or class which interprets the step differently and therefore needs to know if the slice was written as e. g. `1:5` or `1:5:1`.

Comment: ah of course. silly me

Comment: I've added https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/107756 for the docs bug.

Comment: @wim there are other things that I find a little confusing about that section of the docs, but I don't know if it's just me. For example, when it states "Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by 'range(start, stop, step)'", I believe that's only true for positive values.  For example, `slice(-1,0,1)` doesn't see to represent the same indices as specified by `range(-1,0,1)`. Although, that is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48776238/6394617)

Comment: @Joe I agree the range comparison is not very helpful/accurate. Personally, I just think of an instance `slice(x, y, z)` as what you receive in your `__getitem__` from the syntax `obj[x:y:z]`, and don't try to make any analogy with range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slice's step indeed [defaults to `None`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Objects/sliceobject.c#L116-L118), but using step `1` and `None` should be equivalent for all practical purposes. That's because in the C code where the step is actually used, [there are checks which transform `None` into `1` anyway](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Objects/sliceobject.c):

```
int
PySlice_GetIndices(PyObject *_r, Py_ssize_t length,
                   Py_ssize_t *start, Py_ssize_t *stop, Py_ssize_t *step)
{
    PySliceObject *r = (PySliceObject*)_r;
    if (r->step == Py_None) {
        *step = 1;
    } ...    
}
```

And:

```
int
PySlice_Unpack(PyObject *_r,
               Py_ssize_t *start, Py_ssize_t *stop, Py_ssize_t *step)
{
    PySliceObject *r = (PySliceObject*)_r;
    ...
    if (r->step == Py_None) {
        *step = 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you're wondering why they don't just default to `1` instead, perhaps it's because users may still want to slice using `None` explicitly (e.g. `L[1:2:None]`), and/or to give 3rd-party types the opportunity to handle `1` and `None` differently in their `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`/`__delitem__` implementation.

Comment: _"for all practical purposes"_ so for what impractical purposes would it _not_ default to `1`?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Comparing slice instances for equality.

Comment: Where is `PySlice_GetIndices` actually used? I'm assuming, by internal data structures, `list` etc? Because if you create `s = slice(1, 10)` and then `print(s.stop)` it will print `None`, so if you are writing your own data structure that wants to support slices, you have to explicitly handle the `None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's used by the `indices` method of slice instances. I think you meant `s.step` not `s.stop` ... but yeah, sure, if you're writing your own data structure you're not obliged to treat `step=None` and `step=1` as equivalent. In fact you're not even obliged to use integers (I implemented a class once which used slicing with strings to implement a certain functionality..)

Comment: [`slice.indices`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices), and looks like it's also part of the [stable ABI](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/16c9415fba4972743f1944ebc44946e475e68bc4/Misc/stable_abi.toml#L1297-L1298) since 3.2

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of this method. I guess for a given length, then, `slice_object1.indices(some_length) == slice_object2.indices(some_length)` gives the desired semantics.